# Unable to configure Server RunTime Environment on Eclipse due to Tomcat's version

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

`Apache-Tomcat-8.5.4` is already installed and perfectly running on my system via `localhost:8080`. I use `Eclipse` as IDE and am trying to configuring the server runtime environment to run my `.jsp` code, however, it is showing the following version error:

[image]

The problem is Eclipse is expecting `Tomcat v8.0` while I have already installed `v8.5.4`. Although it shouldn't be a problem, it is not allowing me to set-up my runtime environment to execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug with eclipse. Check this 
[link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494936)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Most probably it looks like a bug of Eclipse. In this link, the user is expecting a separate category to choose Tomcat's 8.5 version but I think you should be able to select any of 8.x versions by selecting Apache Tomcat v8.0 server.

Comment: I tested this yesterday, in Neon it worked with Tomcat 9 connector. Search  one jar named like "org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core" in <eclipse>\plugin directory and replace with the one available on this link : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=262418&action=edit

Comment: Thanks for some more info on this. But before I could realize the exact meaning of that link i.e. replacement of a jar with another customized jar, I had changed Eclipse from Neon to Kepler and then Indigo. And finally I had to compromise with Tomcat 7.0 to run my code.

Answer (score 0):

which eclipse version are you using??

try using Eclipse Mars.

or as a work around just try renaming your tomcat installation directory to 8.0

Comment: Earlier it was Eclipse Neon. Then I uninstalled it and downloaded Kepler but the problem seems to be more different now. In Kepler, there is no option to choose Tomcat v8.0 as the list is up to v7.0. I tried with changing the name of the directory too but that didn't work. This is really irritating now.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to use tomcat 8.5.4. May be you can go ahead with 8.0. It should not make much of a difference.

Comment: Yes. Real thing is that Tomcat 8.5.4 is not supported with any of Eclipse (Neon, Indigo, Kepler). Infact the worst part is, in some versions, Tomcat 8 does not even show up in the list.